# How to yank relative line?

Tags: vim

I have relative line numbers turned on.

I can yank line 10 using `:10y`.

But how to I yank say the 5th line below the current line without jumping to said line, yanking and jumping back (i.e. `5jY5k`).

If I had this file:

```
2   describe 'foobar' do
1     it 'should be cool' do
46      # do stuff
1     end
2  end
```

I am on line 46 and I want to yank relative line 1 or 2, either above or below.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `+n` and `-n` for relative addresses:

```
:+2y    " Two lines after the current line
:-2y    " Two lines before the current line
```

And you can also combine this:

```
:-2,+2y   "  Two lines before the cursor and two lines after
```

Also see [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3232/51) for some more examples and [`:help [range]`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#E16) for the Vim documentation.